# Switch function not returning correct value when referencing "nothing"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

having a small issue here.

I have a `Switch` function in a report as shown below:

```
=Switch(

    Fields!Duration.Value > 0, Round(Fields!Duration.Value / 60),

    Fields!LastTime.Value = nothing, "Still Occupied",

    Fields!LastTime.Value = Fields!FirstTime.Value, "Passing By"

)
```

This is for a column that is showing the total "Fields!Duration.Value" in minutes (rounded up), and it is working other than the second line:

If the Last Time value is the same as the First Time value, then it is assumed the object was just passing by and outputs "Passing By" and it does this correctly.

However, if the Last Time value is equal to nothing (it is defined in the column for "Last Time" that if it IsNothing, it is 'nothing', and it should output in this report with "Still Occupied" - which it's not doing. The cell is left blank, as if I have it written as `Fields!LastTime.Value = nothing, nothing,`

Why is this line of code not working?

```
    Fields!LastTime.Value = nothing, "Still Occupied",
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using an IIF statement instead of a Switch statement worked for me, at least for this specific case:

```
=IIF(Fields!Duration.Value > 0, Round(Fields!Duration.Value / 60),
IIF(Fields!LastTime.Value = Fields!FirstTime.Value, "Passing by", "Still Occupied"))
```

Going to try to explain it for future people that might not understand (like me when I eventually forget it - I am very new to this sort of stuff) -

Rather than using the `Switch` statement I had in place to see if `Fields!LastTime.Value` is a **number,** **equal to Fields!FirstTime.Value,** or **nothing,** it now just asks if it is a **number** or if it is  equal to `Fields!FirstTime.Value`, and if neither of those are true, it marks it as "Still Occupied" thus removing the need to reference `nothing` entirely. Like I said, this is pretty case specific, but you never know.

Thank you for the help @JamieSee and @SuperSimmer 44. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test for Nothing using the = operator. There are two ways for which Nothing can be tested; using the IsNothing inspection function like this `IsNothing(Fields!LastTime.Value) = True`, or by using the Is operator like this `Fields!LastTime.Value Is Nothing`.

If these tests do not produce the expected result you may be dealing with a field that is set to something other than NULL, like empty '' or an arbitrary value. You can open the Query Designer on your Dataset properties to run your query and check the results.

You could also be looking at a mismapping with your dataset. Use the Refresh Fields button on your Dataset properties to verify your Field Mappings and then double-check that the name being used in your expression matches.

Comment: `IsNothing` already returns a true or false value so `= True` is redundant.  Additionally, there is another way to check if a field is empty that could improve this answer -- simply `Trim(Fields!LastTime.Value) = ""`.  Otherwise, this answer is the better of the two non-asker answers.

Answer (score -3):

Could be that nothing should be surrounded by " "

Comment: You cannot test for Nothing using the = operator. Try `IsNothing(Fields!LastTime.Value) = True`.

Comment: @JamieSee Didn't work unfortunately. I've currently got `=Switch(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value > 0, Round(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value / 60), IsNothing(Fields!LastInTime.Value) = True, "Not Exited", Fields!LastInTime.Value = Fields!FirstInTime.Value, "Pass-through" )` with your suggestion. Showing the same as before. I should also mention I have tried just `is nothing` but no avail.

Comment: @radwic Changed this to an answer. What's the data type of the field and does it allow/contain a SQL NULL? I suspect this may, in fact, not be Nothing and instead be a blank or a dummy date.

Comment: Hey @JamieSee, the expression in the cell for `Fields!LastTime.Value` tells it to be `nothing` if there is no value so I am certain it is actually nothing. I did figure out a workaround using nested IIFs instead, I will post it.